# UN Parent armature but keep the pose

Tags: armature, parent

I am asking this question as I cannot get this to work using the suggestions in other peoples posts.

I am trying to un parent my mesh from the armature, whilst keeping the pose and the corresponding weights.

Before applying the armature I have :

- I have attempted to set the pose to the rest pose
- Attempted to set the rotation and scale and location (this makes my mesh do weird things)
- Attempted ctrl P > armature deform
- I have attempted baking the action and clearing the parent

None of these have worked. They either retard the mesh, or, when the armature is applied, the mesh loses the pose.

Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Apply the armature modifier. Then unparent.

Comment: Hi Jerryno, when I apply the armature, I lose the pose.

Answer (score 1):

Select your mesh and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> in object mode, select *visual transform* from the list.
your mesh will stay deformed after you un-parent or even delete the armature.

Comment: Hi, I tried this and it did not work. Upon applying my armature, the pose was lost.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to figure out what my issue was. The above answer's did work. However what I failed to mention was I couldn't just 'apply' the armature and was using the 'apply using shape keys' button.

This was due tot he file I imported coming with shape keys (unbeknownst to me as I don't know blender very well). In order for me to have baked my shape, I needed to delete those shape keys under the 'objects' tab and then the 'shape keys' drop down part.

After this, it was as simple as applying the armature, and then deleting it.

Thank you to those who offered their help and advice.